# Exclude date via .exclude

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have been looking everywhere for documentation on excluding time and before and after. Ie My app for school is for appointments. They want me to make sure no one can sign up earlier than the current day. If someone could give me a format I have it so i can strip it down to just the day. But not only an solution to the problem but a link to some great detailed documentation as I need date and time for a lot on this project would be good.

```
'other' : Item.objects.exclude(time |date:"M d, Y"),
```

that is the current code  it does not work. I get invalid syntax. If I take out the () of it my page loads so the () is the issue. Any help would be greatly appropriated.

Comment: Update post with  the code that you had try do, what is the traceback that you get?

Comment: The code I have is that one line right there there is no Trace back get some Text error shuts down the server

Comment: you cannot give it whatever syntax you would like and expect it to work. The `date:` is a django template syntax. Try strftime to format the time in the format you desire

Comment: ok so where can i find documentation on exluding anything with current date in it?

Comment: the queryset accepts a datetime object. Just filter it on the field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to use Django template language in Python code, which won't work. Your queryset should probably look something more like `Item.objects.exclude(time__lt=whatever_time)`. Read the queryset docs linked by @karthikr

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try filtering a date range instead of excluding before and after

```
Item.objects.filter(date__range=["2017-01-01", "2017-01-31"])
```

To exclude before and after something like this should work with `__lt` for less than and `__gt` for greater than:

```
Item.objects.exclude(date__lt=datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)).exclude(date__gt=datetime.date(2017, 1, 31))
```

Comment: While this does exclude everything I need it to just do it for the day ie time now.  is there a way to do that Ie so only future dates show,